# How to Count link with two columns text Result

Tags: excel

**This is Table**

What i want 

**Srinivas** How many **Removed** Count 

**Srinivas** How many **Created** Count

[image]

No I Need Result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the below formula in `Cell E2`

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$17,$D2,$A$2:$A$17,E$1)
```

Drag/Copy down and across (to right) as required.

For total use

```
=SUM(E2:E4)
```

and drag across to right. See image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`=COUNTIFS(RANGE1, THING_IN_RANGE1, RANGE2, THING_IN_RANGE2)`

Put this is the cells you need to count.

Answer (score 2):

Use a pivot table. That's what they are made for. No formulas needed for that.

I suggest you turn the data into an Excel Table object first, by clicking any cell in the data and then Insert > Table and tick the box for "My table has headers".

Next, click a cell in the newly created table, then click Insert > Pivot Table. Drag "Study Director" into the rows box, "Folder Status" into the Columns box and again into the Values box.

When your source data changes, you only need to refresh the pivot table.

The benefit of this approach is that you don't run the risk of missing to add a new name in the data source to your formula setup.

[image]